# Python: Sorting datetime in clustered data using groupby() and apply()

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, pandas-groupby, apply

I'd like to sort the datetime column per cluster.

```
    latitude    longitude   cluster datetime          
0   57.723610   11.925191   1       2021-06-13 14:22:11.682
1   57.723614   11.925187   1       2021-06-13 14:22:13.562
2   57.723610   11.925172   1       2021-06-13 14:22:28.635 
3   57.724075   11.923708   2       2021-06-13 14:23:44.905 
4   57.723637   11.925056   2       2021-06-13 14:22:59.336 
5   57.723614   11.925178   3       2021-06-13 14:22:44.170
6   57.723827   11.924635   3       2021-06-13 14:23:14.479 
7   57.723610   11.925191   3       2021-06-13 14:22:04.000
8   57.723866   11.924005   3       2021-06-13 14:23:29.605
```

For this I am trying to use groupby() and apply():

```
# Converting the time column from object to datetime
df["datetime"]= pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

# Sorting date per cluster
df.groupby("cluster").apply(df.sort_values(by="datetime", inplace=True))
```

However, I am getting the error:

**'NoneType' object is not callable**

My end goal is to then extract to a new df the rows of each cluster corresponding to their earliest (oldest) and latest (most recent) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to groupby for the sorting, just sort first by datetime, then by cluster:

```
df.sort_values(["cluster", "datetime"])
```

However, if you want to get the earliest and latest record in each cluster, you might indeed be better off doing everything inside the groupby:

```
(df.groupby("cluster", as_index=False)
   .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values("datetime")
                     .iloc[[0, -1], :]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a `function` to `apply` method (which is callable).

You can use `lambda` function in `apply` as follows-

```
df = df.groupby("cluster").apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by = 'datetime'))
```